# How do I filter out error responses from API call in python?

Tags: python, rest, pyspark

I'm using python to retrieve some data back from a rest API. I'm looping through a list to get data back for each record that is passed in like so:

```
safety_codes = ['M516RHJ', 'M16AJAR', 'Z49EJ57', 'Z1035TH', 'S0X6DJU9', 'S9099LP', 'S912AZSD', 'S72AEFH', 'S61ABKJ', 'W4XXATF']

#Building API variables:
api_data = dict()
rest_url = "https://www.gencodedemosite.com/restws/empcodes="
response_type = '&format=json'
header_details = {"KEY": "1101079000335WAXMEMU14532"}

#Making API  call:
for i in generic_emp_codes:
    response = requests.get(rest_url+'{}'.format(i)+response_format, headers = header_details)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    api_data.update({i: data})
```

So long as the emp_code is valid I will return some data. But the moment one of those codes are bad, I get the following response and all of the other data is lost.

```
{
    "error": "No record found for given employee safety code."
}
```

How do I filter out the these responses so that my api call does not fall over? Essentially, if codes M516RHJ and M16AJAR return that data. But if Z49EJ57 returns an error message, move that aside and keep the the data for M516RHJ and M16AJAR, then move on to the next code and repeat the process.

```
json_rdd = sc.parallelize(api_data)
json_df = spark.read.json(json_rdd)
json_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

Once I get that error message all of my data becomes corrupted.

Comment: Your code doesn’t seem to copy values from `data` which is the response for one code, to anywhere else like a list of the results - is your real code doing this? Presumably you could check if `data` has a key `error` and ignore that result?

Comment: @barny how would I copy the values from data into a list? I thought that it was supposed to just hold all the values until the last call is finalized? Additionally how do I check to see if data has a key `error` and ignore that result? I'm a little new to API calls.

Comment: adding my full code and results

Comment: Assigning to `data` will remove its previous value. After that line, try e.g. `results.append(data)` after previously initialising `results=[]`.

Comment: Try checking `if ‘error’ in data.keys():` but that depends on that the other results are also all dictionaries. Otherwise you’ll possibly have do something like `if type(data)==dict and ‘error’ in data.keys():`

Comment: @barny do you mind showing me? I'm a little confused still.

Comment: @barny sorry, I was asking about the `data.keys():` part. I don't fully understand that.

Comment: Try printing `data.keys()` or even better read the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict.keys

Answer (score 0):

```
results = []
bad_codes = []
#Making API  call:
for i in generic_emp_codes:
    response = requests.get(rest_url+'{}'.format(i)+response_format, headers = header_details)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    if type(data)==dict and 'error' in data.keys():
        bad_codes.append(data)
    else:
        results.append(data)
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that :-)